# How to prevent insertPost from adding a object in a list if the previous object is empty

Tags: java

I'm trying to make it so that the *insertPost* function doesn't insert a new node into a linked list after an already *null* node.

How can I do this?

class:

```
public void insertPost(No newN, No previousN){

    if (previousN != null){
        newN.setNext(previousN.next());
        previousN.setNext(newN);
    }
}
```

main:

```
    No no1 = new No(null, null);

    LinList lList = new LinkedList(no1);

    No no2 = new No("Tree", null);
    lList.insertPost(no2, no1);

    System.out.print(lList);
```

When printed, the console outputs:

"null, Tree"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no1 is a Node instance containing a null value so you need to find out if the value inside previousN is not null.

```
public void insertAfter(Node newN, Node previousN) {
    if (previousN != null && previousN.getValue() != null) {
        newN.setNext(previousN.next());
        previousN.setNext(newN);
    }
}
```